# Jackson databind working in IDE environment but not in jar

Tags: java, maven, noclassdeffounderror, jackson-databind

I am trying to use jackson databind using Maven. It works fine in my IDE environment (I'm using IntelliJ IDEA), but when I try to make a jar with it, it produces an error on startup and instantly crashes. Specifically, the error is this :

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonFactory
```

This is specific to the JAR, and I don't know why it does that at all.
What did I do wrong ?

Here is the pom file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>me.zam</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-yaml</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <!-- Make this jar executable -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <!-- Jar file entry point -->
                            <mainClass>me.Main</mainClass>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

And here is the Main object

```
package me;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

import java.io.File;

/**
 * Created by Martin on 31/03/2017.
 */
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(new YAMLFactory());
        try {
            User user = mapper.readValue(new File("user.yaml"), User.class);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How you are creating the jar file? and how you running it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I just tried it in my system and was able to reproduce the issue.

To solve it you need to add one more plugin `maven-shade-plugin`, which is required to create the fat jar, i.e. Jar with all the required dependency.

Update pom.xml file, note here I've renamed the class which contains `main` method to `Test` and put into the default package:-

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

        <groupId>com.so</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

        <packaging>jar</packaging>

        <properties>
            <mainClass>Test</mainClass>
        </properties>

        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
                <version>2.2.3</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-yaml</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.0</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>

        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.4.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <createDependencyReducedPom>true</createDependencyReducedPom>
                        <transformers>
                            <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer"/>
                            <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                <mainClass>${mainClass}</mainClass>
                            </transformer>
                        </transformers>
                        <!-- exclude signed Manifests -->
                        <filters>
                            <filter>
                                <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                                <excludes>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                                </excludes>
                            </filter>
                        </filters>
                    </configuration>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <phase>package</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>shade</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
                <!-- Make this jar executable -->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <archive>
                            <manifest>
                                <!-- Jar file entry point -->
                                <mainClass>Test</mainClass>
                                <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            </manifest>
                        </archive>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>

    </project>
```

Once done, I ran the code by running first `mvn clean package` command, which creates the fat jar and then run the code by `java -cp target/jackson-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar Test` command.

Let me know if you face any issue running the code.

Answer (score 1):

Can you please check whether the generated jar contains the specified dependencies such as `jackson-databind` and `jackson-dataformat-yaml`? I'm not sure the jar plugin exports the maven dependencies. I normally use maven assembly plugin or shade plugin to generate jar with dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but you need to change `<mainClass>` to `<MainClass>` and set the scope for the dependency to compile like `<scope>compile</scope>` to add it directly to the jar file.